# v-app not showing page layout using vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using vuetify version 2.3.10. I have a file with layout somewhat like this

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <div>
     <Users />
    </div>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
 import Users from 'views/users.vue';
 export default {
  components: {
    Users
  },
</script>
```

But "Hello" doesn't show on the browser. But if I remove the  tag something like this.

```
<template>
    <div>
      <Users />
    </div>
</template>
```

Then in the browser I am getting this error. Cannot read property 'mobileBreakpoint' of undefined. Please help me resolve this issue.

users.vue(component)

```
<template>
  <div>
      <p>Hello</p>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Shouldn't your import be a relative path or at least prefixed with the `@` alias, eg `import Users from "@/views/users.vue"`?

Comment: @Phil I tried what you import Users from "@/views/users.vue" but it gives me an error, module not found

Comment: @Phil I am using vue as front end in my rails app. So path is views/users.vue

Comment: I literally have no idea what that means. When you use `import`, if it is not a relative or absolute path, it looks in `node_modules` so unless your `users.vue` file is in `node_modules` under a `view` package, your import path is incorrect. Now I'll ask again, what are the paths for your two `.vue` files in your Vue app?

Comment: @Phil for parent file, the path is 'views/index.vue' and the path of the component file is 'views/users.vue'. I am in a process of migration of vuetify version 1.5 to 2.3. This component works for version 1.5 but not working in 2.3. Just extra information if it is of any help.

Comment: Then the path should be `import Users from "./users.vue"`

Comment: @Phil still the same issue. The component doesn't show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

index.js

The issue was here. I forgot to add vuetify : new Vuetify(), and the issue is resolved.

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify';
Vue.use(Vuetify);

new Vue({
 vuetify : new Vuetify(),
...
});
```

Answer (score -1):

In your Users component there should be an `export default` statement as well (without it you can't import it later) and give it the `name: 'Users'` for good measure as well. Then it should work as intended. Better also store your components in `components`. `views` are meant for everything that has an own `route`.

Users.vue

```
<template>
  <div><p>Hello</p></div>
</template>

<script>
 export default {
  name: 'Users',
 }
</script>
```

Other.vue

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <div>
     <Users />
    </div>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
 import Users from '@/components/users.vue';
 export default {
  components: {
    Users
  },
</script>
```

Comment: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@/components/users.vue'. I have stored users component in components folder

Comment: @user12763413 Sorry I don't know your exact project structure and placement of files in it so I have to guess the path a bit. But because the at sign points to the src folder it should actually work.

Answer (score -1):

I am in a process of migration of vuetify version 1.5 to 2.3 like you

in my case,

contains minus z-index

check your style sheet